# writing on a photo (from sdcard) using set type face

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to capture photo from camera but i don't know how to write on it using set type face method in android studio.please give me both layout and activity.

please help me know how can i write on picture with feature like color or different fonts?

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can do but it is for a picture of resources, you can    modify it to bring your saved image. if you can not do let me know.

```
  public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context mContext,  int resourceId,  String mText) {
try {
     Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId);

        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =   bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if(bitmapConfig == null) {
          bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // resource bitmaps are imutable,
        // so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        // new antialised Paint
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // text color - #3D3D3D
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(110,110, 110));
        // text size in pixels
        paint.setTextSize((int) (12 * scale));
        // text shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.DKGRAY);

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/6;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/5;

      canvas.drawText(mText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);

        return bitmap;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception



    return null;
}
```

}